# Capture groups of text via a Bash script

Tags: regex, bash, grep

A file that looks like the following is created from an API call.

```
{
  "success" : true,
  "messages" : [ "traces loaded successfully" ],
  "traces" : [ "CRXJ-ZCKP-3XVD-4J36", "8C31-QMHZ-XVF0-ZV4Q", "40P7-MT6L-2YFP-5Q6Q", "JE7J-J4WQ-7GGL-2U8N", "10PW-AZ8M-FPTK-XWYL", "9YGF-5HOP-8GTY-9AF4", "SNXZ-GW6O-BTJT-3XUX" ]
}
```

How can I capture each traces separately?
I will need to iterate through them in a subsequent step.

The following doesn't return anything unless I remove the parentheses. Then it just gives the entire "traces" line.

```
grep "([A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4})"
```

The answer must be able to run on all Unix machines without loading libraries.

Comment: you may try the option -o.

Comment: Why do you want to parse a `JSON` text with `grep` and not a syntax aware tool like `jq`?

Comment: @Inian, this script must be able to run on all Unix machines without loading libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -oE '([A-Z0-9]+-?){4}' file
```

---

Options:

```
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
-E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
```

---

Output:

```
CRXJ-ZCKP-3XVD-4J36
8C31-QMHZ-XVF0-ZV4Q
40P7-MT6L-2YFP-5Q6Q
JE7J-J4WQ-7GGL-2U8N
10PW-AZ8M-FPTK-XWYL
9YGF-5HOP-8GTY-9AF4
SNXZ-GW6O-BTJT-3XUX
```

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/OQExD6/3)

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -oE`:

```
grep -oE '[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}' file
```

Output:

```
CRXJ-ZCKP-3XVD-4J36
8C31-QMHZ-XVF0-ZV4Q
40P7-MT6L-2YFP-5Q6Q
JE7J-J4WQ-7GGL-2U8N
10PW-AZ8M-FPTK-XWYL
9YGF-5HOP-8GTY-9AF4
SNXZ-GW6O-BTJT-3XUX
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also stay in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regex='("(([[:alnum:]]{4}-?){4})"(, )?)+'

while read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]]
    then
        for trace in ${BASH_REMATCH[0]//[\",]/}
        do
            echo "do stuff with $trace"
        done
    fi
done<input_file
```